# Compare strings after removing extra whitespace in an efficient way

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> oranges = "10 100                  200"
>>> oranges == "10 100 200"
False
>>> apples = "10 20 30"
>>> apples == "10 20 30"
True
```

Expecting output for oranges is True for `"10 100                  200"` in my case.

I am looking  for whether 10 100 200 are present in order wise . I tried striping but it will do only start of the string and end of the string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should do splitting instead of stripping:

```
oranges1 = "10 100                  200"
oranges2 = "10 100 200"
oranges1.split() == oranges2.split()
#True
```

Answer (score 5):

Split your strings on whitespace and compare to a list of the values you expect:

```
oranges = '10         100 200'
oranges.split() == ['10', '100', '200']
>>> True
```

The docs for the string method `split()` are here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Your question refers to Python 2. This solution will work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex as follows:

```
import re

oranges1 = "10 100                  200"
oranges2 = "10 100 200"

print re.sub("[\x00-\x20]+", " ", oranges1) == re.sub("[\x00-\x20]+", " ", oranges2)
```

**output:**

```
True
```